# Fetch from API not showing data

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to this and have probably missed an important step. I'm having trouble retrieving data from my API using the Fetch () method. The only thing shown is the link to the API and not the content. I want to get the Author and title of the books inside the API and print it in a list when u make a call with the button. But I have a hard time moving on when I can not retrieve data via the Fetch method.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

function BookSearch() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

function handleChange(event) {
  const book = event.target.value;
  const onInputChange = e => {
  setBook(book);
  setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}
};

  let url = `http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title`;
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setBooks(data));
    window.open(setBooks.url);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="search">
        <h1>Search movie</h1>
        <form>
        <input type="text"/>
        <button onClick={url}> Click me </button>
        
  );
}



export default BookSearch;
```

Comment: result is undefined !! from where you get this information ?
setBooks.url setBooks is the function to setState you need to use books.url instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './style.css';
    
    function BookSearch() {
      const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
      const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    
    function handleChange(event) {
      const book = event.target.value;
      const onInputChange = e => {
      setBook(book);
      setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }
    };
    
    const handleClick = () => {
      let url = `http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=react`;
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setBooks(data));
    }
      
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="search">
            <h1>Search movie</h1>
            <form>
            <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}/>
            <button onClick={handleClick}> Click me </button>
            <table>
                <tr>
                  <th> Author </th>
                  <th> Title </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
              {result.map(book => (  
              <div className="result">  
              {book.author_name} 
               {book.title} 
            </form>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      );
    }
```

Comment: Hmm no, strange .. I still not get any information from the API

Comment: url is a method and you are assigning value as Let that is wrong otherwise code is fine

Comment: from where you get result.map ???

Comment: I mean onclick = {url} is a method so you are again assigning value to url as a variable

Comment: I mean by it's books.map()

Comment: Okey, can you show me in the code example what u mean?

Comment: create a codesanbox send me a link I will solve it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out the react component life cycle to understand more:

> https://blog.logrocket.com/react-lifecycle-methods-tutorial-examples/
>
> https://tsh.io/blog/react-component-lifecycle-methods-vs-hooks/

In this situation you need to create a function for the button, in your code you linked just the string.
You can try something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const BookSearch = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    let url = 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=react';

const handleChange = (event) => {
    const book = event.target.value;
    setBooks(book);
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
};

const simpleButtonFunction = (e) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setBooks(data);
            window.open(setBooks.url);
        });
};

return (
    <div>
        <div className="search">
            <h1>Search movie</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" />
                <button onClick={simpleButtonFunction}> Click me </button>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Author </th>
                        <th> Title </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {books.map(book => (
                    <div className="result">
                        {book.author_name}
                        {book.title}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default BookSearch;
```

Comment: from where you get result.map ???